# Is every rational number raised to a rational power an algebraic number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-systems

Question is pretty much explained in the title. My inclination is to say "yes", but I'm unsure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure; pretty much by definition, $r^{p/q}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^q = r^p$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. $\displaystyle \left( \frac{a}{b}\right) ^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is a root of $\displaystyle b^p x^q - a^p = 0$.

Comment: Oh, Qiaochu is so speedy.